# error occured while installing hive 3.1.2

Tags: java, hive

When I try to install hive 3.2.1 , I am getting error as

```
C:\apache-hive-3.1.2-bin\bin>hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/hadoop-3.2.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2021-12-04T22:07:08,270 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - Found configuration file file:/C:/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/conf/hive-site.xml
2021-12-04T22:07:08,804 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - HiveConf of name hive.server2.enable.impersonation does not exist
2021-12-04T22:07:10,221 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - HiveConf of name hive.server2.enable.impersonation does not exist
Hive Session ID = c185b9f3-85dc-43c6-88aa-98abdeaf24e0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:413)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliSessionState.<init>(CliSessionState.java:60)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
..............
```

I copied
`C:\db-derby-10.15.2.0-bin\lib  *.jar` files to `C:\apache-hive-3.1.2-bin\lib` .

And I installed **hadoop3.2.2** and **java 11 versions**